# angular4 application is not working in smart tv's web browser(WebOSBrowser)

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, lg, smart-tv

I tried to deploy my angular4 application in server and its working fine in desktop browsers as well as in mobile browser.Now I want to browse the application from a smart Tv , But its showing a blank page instead of application, what could be the actual issue to browse my application on smart tv ?
    Guys please help me if i need to add any dependencies especially for smart tv(WebOS Browser).

Angular CLi Project ::(.angular-cli.json)

```
`{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "project_name"
  },
  "apps": [`enter code here`
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "./../WebContent",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "rieterFavicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
      "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
      "app/resources/js/jquery-3.2.1.js",
      "app/resources/js/theme-switch.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}`
```

pcakage.json

`{
  "name": "project_name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@ng2-dynamic-forms/core": "^1.4.18",
    "@ng2-dynamic-forms/ui-primeng": "^1.4.18",
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.1",
    "angular-file-saver": "^1.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng2-page-scroll": "^4.0.0-beta.7",
    "ng2-scroll-to": "^1.0.7",
    "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
    "primeng": "^4.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}`

Comment: It means the browser does not support some of the APIs used in the angular app. To replicate this on a desktop browser, IE for example, go ahead and remove your polyfills, and run your app in IE, it will show a blank screen, then open the console, hit refresh, it will tell you which API it does not support

Comment: Ok, I will check. thank-you

Comment: Any updates regarding your issue please, as we face the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had same issue, for me works uncomment in polyfills.ts this imports

```
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';

 import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
```

Comment: why would deactivating ecmascrip partst support help?

Comment: @PatrickArtner by uncommenting this , then it will start supporting those components in browser.

Comment: I tried this. But it still does not work. Smart TV only shows loading and white page.

Answer (score 0):

In angular 8. please change tsconfig.json file -"target": "es2015", to  "target": "es5",

Comment: I am using Angular 6 and have target as es5 but still same issue...